# AMQP + Android libraries

Tags: android, amqp

Is any [amqp](http://www.amqp.org) libraries for Android?

Comment: I just added a link to "amqp" for the ppl like me who didn't know what it is.

Comment: Check out http://simonwdixon.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/getting-started-with-rabbitmq-on-android-part-1/

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how well integrated with Android you want it to be.

There's the [RabbitMQ Java Client](http://www.rabbitmq.com/java-client.html).  It should work on Android, but it hasn't been tested for this, and it will almost certainly need some changes.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the RabbitMQ Java Client only works with AMQP 0-9. If you have an AMQP 1-0 broker it will not work. The Apache Qpid Client works with AMQP 1-0 but uses javax. An alternative is to use an HTTP-AMQP bridge. In other words, a component that translates HTTP requests into AMQP messages. A simple example of such a bridge can be found at https://github.com/profmocs/amqp_http_bridge.